# hibernate default schema ignored when sequence generated

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, entitymanager, spring-orm

I'm working on modular project `JPA`+ `hibernate` + `Spring`, part of entities in are in common project.
I have two webApp who share this common project and two `oracle schemas` (users) FACTURATION and SAV.

I added FACTURATION in first core-application and SAV in the second. Tables are generated in the two schemas.

But the sequences (`@SequenceGenerator`) are generated in a single schema.

Comment: Go though http://vladmihalcea.com/2014/07/08/hibernate-identity-sequence-and-table-sequence-generator/

Answer (score 1):

It looks like is a [known issue](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-7232): Hibernate ignores a the attribute `schema` inside of the `@SequenceGenerator`.

As a workaround for old versions of hibernate (it looks like it have been fixed in the newest version) you can add the following line to your hibernate properties (it worked for me):

```
hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings=true
```